# How to stop WHERE at first occurrence?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Expecting a `mytable` where `x` can have the same value on multiple rows, but we only want to catch the first (or last) occurrence.

Target Qry:

```
select * 
from my_table 
where x IN ('A', 'B', 'C') <<some limit to get the first occurrence>>;
```

And an example `mytable` (first row is column names):

```
x y
A 5
A 1
A 3
B 3
B 2
C 8
```

Target Response (first occurrence):

```
x y
A 5
B 3
C 8
```

Can this may be archived using sub-queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (x) x, y
from my_table 
where x in ('A', 'B', 'C') 
order by x, id
```

Important: it is unclear what you mean by *first* occurence, as your sampl table does not exhibit a column that can be used to order the records. I still assumed that such a column exists, and is called `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a column defining order (ca be incremental order or date)

Last occurence:

```
 select * from my_table a where not exists( select * from my_table b where a.x  = b.x  and 

  a.columnOrder  < b.columnOrder)
```

First occurence:

```
 select * from my_table a where not exists( select * from my_table b where a.x  = b.x  and 

  a.columnOrder  > b.columnOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, unless you specify an ORDER BY, there is simply no concept of "first occurrence" - the order of records you get tomorrow may well be different to what you get today. Instead group and aggregate:

```
SELECT x, MAX(y) as y
FROM table 
GROUP BY x
```

This produces the highest occurrence (equivalent of "first occurrence when order by descending")

It doesn't work for more than one aggregated column though; if you have two or more columns to retrieve, try:

```
SELECT x, y, z
FROM (SELECT x, y, z, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) r
WHERE r = 1
```

This produces every distinct x, the lowest y and the associated z

Answer (score 0):

Some databases have a ROWID hidden column that you can use

```
SELECT x, y
FROM my_table P
WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM my_table WHERE x = P.x)
```